# How to combine two image (png) files to print them in duplex using AppleScript

Tags: shell, printing, applescript, automator

Right, so I'll try and explain this as clearly as possible;

As soon as two files are placed in the folder, I want a Folder Action to 
print these files - got that...

but, and this is my problem. At the moment it prints the files after each other, and I want to make sure that they are printed together, duplex.

so far I've got this:

```
    on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
    do shell script "defaults write com.apple.print.custompresets com.apple.print.lastPresetPref Duplex"


    tell application "Finder" to print these_items
end adding folder items to
```

so I reckon I need to combine/append the two files - so the printer sees them as one, and only one print job is the result, thus creating a duplex printed file :D

would be awesome if you have tips/ideas on how to solve this!
cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a python script written by Martin Michel which will combine multiple images into one file. It should help you solve your problem... find it [here](http://files.macscripter.net/joy/files/combimgs.py). You may want to use image events to resize the images first before passing it to this script so they will fit properly on one printed page.

Comment: Thanks for the response! - ok, I tried running the Python through Automator with a Run Shell Script, with Shell set to /usr/bin/python... but then I think I'm missing something, as I get an error and no further response from the script - just an error. First time working with Python, so I might be missing something quite obvious. Thanks for the reply and help though!! If you have ideas about "what now" I'd love to hear them!!
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple Automator Folder action, which would create a multipage PDF from the added image files, then either print it directly in Automator, or pass it on to an AppleScript in order to set your printer preferences.

[image: Automator Folder Action screenshot]

Comment: First of all, thanks for the reply!
I tried the above before, the problem I get with this though is in between these two actions. When adding the AppleScript (shell script) I get the following results:
1. A warning from Automator saying "The action Print Finder Items was not supplied with required data"
2. The printer does not print duplex (yet)
3. The printer appears to be printing on A2 size - so only one fourth of the page is displayed on the print...

If you have any ideas on how to continue I'd love to know!
Cheers